# How to change TextEdit border color during user input validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress-wpf

How to change TextEdit border color in WPF form during user input validation using DevExpress

I have item in my form:

```
<dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtTextEdit"
 Text="{Binding FilterField, 
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 ValidateOnTextInput="False"
 Validate="txtValidate"/>
```

Also created void to validate this field:

```
private void txtValidate(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ValidationEventArgs e)


{
if (e.Value == null) return;
if (e.Value.ToString().Length > 4) return;
e.IsValid = false;
e.ErrorType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Warning;
e.ErrorContent = "Enter more than 4 symbols";
}
```

And how to change border color instead of showing error?

Comment: you will have to do binding for the `BorderBrush` depending on the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding MyBorderBrush}">
<dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtTextEdit"
 Text="{Binding FilterField, 
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 ValidateOnTextInput="False"
 Validate="txtValidate"/>
</Border>
```

and this in the method,

```
e.IsValid = false;
e.ErrorType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.ErrorType.Warning;
e.ErrorContent = "Enter more than 4 symbols";
MyBorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

`MyBorderBrush` is property. You need to define proper binding. Its datatype should be of `Brush` which is from `System.Windows.Controls`. You need to use this library.

Comment: Sorry, it is `B`, I typed `b`

Comment: And how and where describe MyBorderBrush to bind?

Comment: Bind it the way you bind usually.